# Clear jqgrid toolbar in Chrome

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, webforms

I want to clear the toolbar of my grid.
 I use this code:

```
$("#List1")[0].clearToolbar();
```

This code work fine in Firefox but in Chrome raise this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

How can i fix this problems

Comment: what version of jqgrid do you use?

Comment: Could you provide the demo, which can be used to reproduce the problem?  You can use for example http://jsfiddle.net/